# Is it possible to successfully link against static linux libraries with different exported APIs but with the same object names?

Tags: c, linux, linker

I have two linux static libraries.

They are compiled entirely separately and have different names and the APIs they publish are distinct, but the C files they are built from use the same names - so the object files the libraries are composed from have the same names.

When I come to link against those libraries, will I have problems linking because the object names are the same, even though the function names are unique?

Comment: If you are sure of that they are all static libraries just with same names, then you can rename one of them and link both into your program

Comment: The libraries have different names - just that at least some of the files they build from have the same names.

Comment: as you says, the funciton names in the two libraries are unique, that means there is no conflict while linking them to your program, or the complier will give you warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

The names of the `.o` (object) files are irrelevant. As long as they do not define external functions/objects (in the C sense of object, not the "object file" sense) with duplicate names, you're fine.

Comment: Thankyou! (blah blah extra blah)

Comment: (Any editing improvement which obstructs people saying thankyou is harmful).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with static libraries having the same filename - you can just link them using absolute file paths to avoid the ambiguity. As long as they do not have any common *symbol* names (i.e. any exported functions or variables with the same name) you should be fine.

That said, having two libraries with the same name is a recipe for confusion and future disaster, not to mention that it will complicate things if you ever decide to link those libraries dynamically.

If I were you, I would investigate possible solutions for resolving this naming conflict at the project management level. Perhaps one of the two could be renamed with minimal hassle?

Comment: The library names are distinct - only the names of the C files they are compiled from are shared.

Comment: @BlankXavier: that is not a problem either. It's common symbol names that would cause a conflict...